# Do not wait for database result in async view in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, async-await, django-views

I have an async view in Django 3.1:

```
async def log_click(request):
    await sync_to_async(Click.objects.create)(author=request.user)
    return HttpResponse('<html>Clicked</html>')
```

Is it possible to improve the performance of this view by not needing to wait for `Click` instance's creation? I tried omitting `await` and using [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task):

```
async def log_click(request):
    asyncio.create_task(sync_to_async(Click.objects.create)(author=request.user))
    return HttpResponse('<html>Clicked</html>')
```

however in this case the `Click` instance is not created at all. I want this view to finish execution as fast as possible, but still get `Click` instance created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake in my code. The `asyncio.create_task()` is async function, hence it needs `await` statement:

```
async def log_click(request):
    await asyncio.create_task(sync_to_async(Click.objects.create)(author=request.user))
    return HttpResponse('<html>Clicked</html>')
```

Comment: I did try something similar when looking at your question yesterday, without any luck. May I ask what version of python you are using and what local server are you using for testing? (does runserver know how to process this?)

Comment: @romaingz I used Python 3.8.5 and Django 3.1. Yes, I have tested and everything worked fine using `manage.py runserver` command. I have also wrote a working test using `django.test.TransactionTestCase`.